# In same expression, simultaneously use value and assign variable in Scala

Tags: scala, syntax, scala-2.10, scala-2.11, scala-2.12

Is there a way in Scala to assign a variable a value and at the same time use the value in the expression?  Like so...

```
java.lang.Math.abs(scala.util.Random.nextInt()) / {val num = java.lang.Math.pow(10, (java.lang.Math.abs(scala.util.Random.nextInt() % 5) + 1)) } * num
```

I got this error...

```
cannot be applied to (Unit)
       java.lang.Math.abs(scala.util.Random.nextInt()) / {val num = java.lang.Math.pow(10, java.lang.Math.abs(scala.util.Random.nextInt() % 7)) } * num
```

In order to round down to a variable exponentiation of the value '10', I want to assign some random integer to the variable "num" use the same value in an expression at same time. So then I can make sure num will be the same value for the divisor will be the same as the multiplier. I know I have seen something in scala that made me think I can do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might put your nums in a 2-element collection and then `reduce()` it.

```
Seq(Math.abs(util.Random.nextInt())
   ,Math.pow(10, Math.abs(util.Random.nextInt() % 5) + 1))
  .reduce((a,b) => /*use as many a's and b's as needed*/)
```